# How much did the ancient Greeks know of non-Euclidean geometry?

Tags: ancient-greece, non-euclidean-geometry

They knew the Earth was a sphere, and Eratosthenes even computed the radius. Menelaus and possibly Hipparchus knew that the angles inside a triangle add to more than $\pi$ on a sphere.

Did they have something like the concept of curvature? Did they know the perimeter and area of the disc on a sphere? Did they know anything about hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: Ancient studies did not extend beyond properties of lines (great circles) and triangles, albeit intricate ones, see [Papadopoulos](https://hal.science/hal-01064269/document). Chasles, writing in 1837, says that even spherical circles began to be studied "only about forty years ago". Greeks did not have a concept of curvature (even for curves), nor did they know anything about hyperbolic geometry (the earliest inklings come from medieval Islamic mathematicians). [English translation](https://scholarworks.calstate.edu/concern/theses/2514nk93v) of Menelaus' Sphaerica is freely accessible.

Comment: As for the disc on a sphere, Archimedes computed its area as a byproduct of considering the whole sphere, and computing its perimeter is not a challenge (it's just a circle). However, I have no reason to believe anyone thought of it as a disc (in the intrinsic sense) and not just a spherical cap.